# Postfix and multidomain

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, mx-record

I'm trying to setup postfix to use multi-domains mail.

Right now, I can send mails to `user@ns3289160.ip-5-135-180.eu`, but sending mails to `user@domain2.com` isn't working: I receive the following email while trying to send emails to this address

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     user@domain2.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain domain2.com by redirect.ovh.net. [213.186.33.5].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 sorry, no mailbox here by that name (#5.1.1)
```

**main.cf**

```
myhostname = domain1.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = ns3289160.ip-5-135-180.eu, localhost.ip-5-135-180.eu, localhost
virtual_alias_domains = domain2.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual/addresses
```

**/etc/postfix/virtual/addresses**

```
domain2.com         DOMAIN
user@domain2.com    user
```

I genuinely have no clue about what's going on, knowing that I never switch my MX entries on my domain name (it still points to redirect.ovh.net, that stands for, according to their documentation, the mx for personnal mailboxes).

How can I properly set everything up so that I can be able to use postfix with a personalized mail address ? (such as `domain1.com` instead of `ns**.eu`)

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.1-Ubuntu <<>> domain2.com mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15795
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0005 , udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;domain2.com.               IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
domain2.com.        5       IN      MX      1 redirect.ovh.net.

;; Query time: 156 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 02 18:26:12 EDT 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76
```

*The names domain2.com, user have been changed...*

Comment: What's the output of `dig domain2.com mx`?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: well, that's the problem. Please setup mx record of `domain2.com` to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to receive mail with your VPS, you need to point the MX to your server. Now it's pointing to `redirect.ovh.net` so the virtual aliases has to be configured there as redirects, not destinations. You could have for example:

```
mail.example.com.   IN   A     5.135.180.55
example.com.        IN   MX 1  mail.example.com.
```

This is not a Postfix issue and your Postfix is probably configured correctly. Just remember to `postmap` the virtual alias table if it isn't.